# Basic procedure while adding an additional controller to a module in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, module, configuration, controllers

I am trying to create a new controller for a module. I have set the frontend layout XML file and corresponding template file. I have flushed the cache too. Still it's showing a 404 error. What am I doing wrong here? If I need to mention more information for answers, please do mention.

```
<?php

namespace Mine\Hello\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class Googi extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Hello Landing page.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        // Set title of page
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Something'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**routes.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="hello" frontName="hello">
            <module name="Mine_Hello" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

The URL I am specifying is `Magento/hello/index/googi`.

Comment: Please put the content of routes.xml file and your controller file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new controller you first you need to create `routes.xml` in below location,

`app\code\YOUR_VENDORNAME\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\etc\frontend\routes.xml`

In this file, you need to write this code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="SOME_UNIQUQ_ID" frontName="mytest">
            <module name="YOURVENDORNAME_YOURMODULENAME" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Where `mytest` is my route name you can replace with your

Now you need to create a layout file in below file,

`app\code\YOUR_VENDORNAME\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\view\frontend\layout\mytest_index_index.xml`

here you can see `mytest_index_index` where `mytest` is route name `index` is controller name and `index` is action name.

in this layout file you need to write your as per your requirement. for example

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>TEST TITLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="YOUR_VENDOR\YOUR_MODULENAME\Block\MyBLock" name="myForm" template="YOURVENDOR_YOURMODULE::form.phtml" />            
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you need to create a block `YOUR_VENDOR\YOUR_MODULENAME\Block\MyBLock` and you can add your content

Now you need to create a controller in

`app\code\YOUR_VENDORNAME\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\Controller\Index.php`

And last but not the least execute below command,

- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 1):

Following step may be help you step

- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento c:f
- Check route front name from vendor/module/etc/frontend/route.xml file.
- Make sure your controller action file inside the vendor/module/Controller/ControllerNameFolder/ActionNameFile.
- Then hit BaseUrl/frontname/controller/action
- If still having issue , debug controller by adding exit and die function in execute function . To check whether controller is working or not .

Comment: have tried that, i have put more info in the question, please refer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check thru this command is your module is enabled. Seems that it's not yet enabled, you can check this through:

> php bin/magento module:status

You can confirm that the module is not yet enabled if it's below "List of disabled modules:" You can enable it through:

> php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module # <- replace this with your module

Afterwards, you can try

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Then check again at your browser if you still encounter the 404 error.